# Export Feature class to WFS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wfs, arcgis-online

how to create WFS from feature class, do i have to have Arcgis Server or is it possible throw Arcgis Online ? (Version 10.3)

Comment: You have two different questions here, but GSE policy is one question per Question. Please **edit** the question to meet our Q&A format by choosing the most important issue. You should also specify the GIS software in use (including version, and if ArcGIS,  which license level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked two question as below

**WFS to Feature Class**

You can easily use interoperability estension to pull wfs service and convert to feature class

[image: wfs-featureclass]

**Feature Class to WFS**

As Wikipedia says [WFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service) is best categorized as a non-RESTful RPC type ***service***- i think you need gis web server (that generates REST or SOAP services) e.g. arcgis server, geoserver, mapserver etc that supports WFS output.

If Arc gis online supports WFS (not WMS) protocol then you can generate it easily and call in a handful of client like arcgis desktop, explorer etc.